# First character goes missing

Tags: c, string, compilation

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(){
   time_t rawtime;
   struct tm *info;
   char buf[80];

   time(&rawtime);
   info= localtime(&rawtime);

   //Wed Nov 30 17:00:54 2022
   strftime(buf, 80, "%a %b %d %X %Y ", info);

   //time zone msia = MST
   char zone[5]={'M','S','T'};
   int carr1= 13, line1= 10;
   char carriage= carr1, linefeed= line1;

   zone[4]= carriage;
   zone[5]= linefeed;

   //concat
    int len1= strlen(buf);
    for (int len2=0; len2<5; len1++, len2++){
        buf[len1]=zone[len2];
    }

    printf("%s",buf);
}
```

I expect to get Thu Dec 12 xx:xx:xx MST, however it only outputs starting from second index and becomes hu Dec 12 xx:xx:xx MST. I don't quite understand why it does that after manually concatenating it.

Comment: Why don't you do `char zone[] = "MST\n";` instead of whatever you're doing?

Comment: And what are you actually trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

`zone[5]= linefeed;` is writing to the *6th* element of `zone` which only has 5 elements.  And the location where `zone[5]` would be is the same as where `buf[0]` is (at least for me and, apparently, for you, though I don't think that is guaranteed).

Comment: Yes, found this as my error and now it works like normal again. TQ!